# Django Rest Serializer: Use nested serializer on GET but not POST

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

The problem is as follows: In the code below I have a `PreguntaSerializer`. As it is coded now if I post a JSON like this:

```
{
    "categoria_pregunta": 1,
    "titulo": "Pregunta de Prueba",
    "descripcion": "Esta es la pregunta que mando por Postman",
    "persons": [1, 3, 5, 3050]
}
```

everything works, but when I retrieve the data I get `categoria_pregunta` and `persons` the same way I have posted them (as int and array respectively). I would like to be able to get those fields using `Categoria_preguntaSerializer` and `PersonForPreguntaSerializer`, but if I change `categoria_pregunta` and `persons` in `PreguntaSerializer` for their respectives serializers, I get errors when posting the before mentioned JSON.
Is there a way I can use the same `PreguntaSerializer` for both actions or should I separate my views for `GET` and `POST` and use different serializers?

**models.py**

```
class Categoria_pregunta(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(
        'Descripcion', null=True, blank=True, max_length=150, default='')
    status = models.IntegerField(
        'Estado', null=True, blank=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

class Pregunta(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, default='')
    descripcion = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    categoria_pregunta = models.ForeignKey(
        Categoria_pregunta, null=True, blank=False, max_length=20)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=False, max_length=20)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=False, max_length=20)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre', null=True,
        blank=False, max_length=1000, default='')
    lastname = models.CharField(
        'Apellido', null=True, blank=False, max_length=1000, default='')
    ...
```

***serializers.py***

```
class Categoria_preguntaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Categoria_pregunta
        fields = ('id', 'nombre',)

class PersonForPreguntaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'lastname')

class PreguntaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usuario = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    categoria_pregunta = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Categoria_pregunta.objects.all())
    persons = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Person.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Pregunta
        exclude = ('status', )
```

***views.py***

```
class ListaPregunta(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Pregunta.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = PreguntaSerializer
```

Comment: can you add your `views.py` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override `to_representation()` method
Try this,

```
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer


class PreguntaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usuario = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    categoria_pregunta = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Categoria_pregunta.objects.all())
    persons = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Person.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Pregunta
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if self.context['request'].method == 'POST':
            user = UserSerializer(instance.usuario).data
            categoria_pregunta = Categoria_preguntaSerializer(instance.categoria_pregunta).data
            persons = PersonForPreguntaSerializer(instance.persons, many=True).data
            data = {"id": instance.id,
                    "usuario": user,
                    "categoria_pregunta": categoria_pregunta,
                    "persons": persons,
                    "titulo": instance.titulo,
                    "descripcion": instance.descripcion
                    }
            return data
        return Serializer.to_representation(self, instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have two different fields for read and write purpose. You can add a new field in the serializer `persons_data` which can be used for getting the list of persons data in serialized format.

Sample code:

```
class PreguntaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usuario = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    categoria_pregunta = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Categoria_pregunta.objects.all())
    persons_data = PersonForPreguntaSerializer(source='persons', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pregunta
        exclude = ('status', )
```

Since you are using `exclude` in `Meta` class, `persons` field will already be included in both read and write which will accept list of primary key ids which you are passing in the request json.

You can also look into `.to_representation()` and `.to_internal_value()` methods of the serializer.

From documentation

> `.to_representation()` - Override this to support serialization, for read operations.
>   `.to_internal_value()` - Override this to support deserialization, for write operations.

Comment: This answer works. I just like to keep the field names consistent and the other answer shows exactly that.